# Why WP About Author plugin doesnt shows here proper URL.?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have installed **WP About Author plugin** on my wordpress blog now here as shown in snapshot

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-about-author/screenshots/

now when i click on Twitter or Facebook Link on that then it redirect to the

http://shareprogrammingtips.com/c-language-programming-tips/why-variables-can-not-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement-just-after-labels/www.twitter.com/jigar_32

instead of just

http://www.twitter.com/jigar_32

How to change this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix your urls with http:// or it will be appended to the base path